# Spring boot aop advices are not getting trigger while using kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-aop

I have been trying to configure an aspect to log but it is not working at all, I am using kotlin and Spring boot , I have added enabled AspectJ in configration using annotation but it is still not working.

```
@Aspect
@Component
class LoggingAspect {

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)
    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository *)" +
            " || within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Service *)")
    fun springBeanPointcut() {
    }


    @Pointcut("within(com.xxxxx.backendcommon.domain.repository..*)" +
            " || within(com.xxxxx.backendcommon.service..*)")
    fun applicationPackagePointcut() {
    }
    @Around(value = "applicationPackagePointcut() & springBeanPointcut()")
    @Throws(Throwable::class)
    fun around(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Any {
        log.debug("Enter: {}.{}() with argument[s] = {}", joinPoint.signature.declaringTypeName,
                joinPoint.signature.name, Arrays.toString(joinPoint.args))
        val result = joinPoint.proceed()
        log.debug("Exit: {}.{}() with result = {}", joinPoint.signature.declaringTypeName,
                joinPoint.signature.name, result)
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that might be wrong here, but in general, Spring AOP is working in Kotlin. I have used a very similar aspect in Java and Kotlin projects and it's working just the same in either.

One thing to remember, [Spring AOP is proxy-based](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies), so it can only advice **non-final**, **public** methods of **Spring beans** that are not called from within a bean (**no self-invocation**).

For a Kotlin project you may want to use the `allopen` compiler plugin to make classes and methods open by default.

Spring Data Repositories are usually not annotated with `@Repository`, but usually extend from a sub-interface of `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository`. So your repository pointcut will not work. Try this instead:

```
 @Pointcut("within(org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+)")
 fun withinRepository() {}
```

With this you should be able to log the actual method calls of `SimpleJpaRepository` (the default Spring Data repository implementation).

You have a typo in your `@Around`, pointcuts are combined with `&&` not `&`. Anyway, I would try it without the package pointcut first, to see if the bean pointcut is working.